# problem to connect two pc with python socket

Tags: python, sockets

I wrote simple client server porgram.And i want to connect two pc by this code.My server pc is connected by wifi and the server code is:

```
import socket

HOST=''
PORT=50007

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST,PORT))

while True:
    try:
        s.listen(1)
        conn, addr=s.accept()
        print('Connected by',addr)
        while 1:
            data=conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            conn.send(data)
            print(data.decode('utf-8'))
        conn.close()
    except:
        print('Client disconnected')
```

My client pc is connected by usb modem.And client code is:

```
import socket

HOST='192.168.1.111'
PORT=50007

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
while True:
    print('Enter your text:')
    output=input()
    s.send(output.encode('utf-8'))
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print ('Posted')
```

This host is my server pc's ipv4 address. If i run this client and server program in one pc  this works correctly but when i try to connect by indivisual pc this client can't connect with server and this error occur on client terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\project\final\client.py", line 7, in <module>
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Why this error occur if try to connect client with server from indivisual pc.What can i do.....??

Comment: Checked firewall on server?

Comment: NO...How to check...??

Comment: Depends on your type of OS. Anyway, firewall management is out of scope for  this site

Comment: I am using windows 10 @grapes

Comment: great, goto `Control Panel` and type `firewall` in search box

Comment: okk...then.......@grapes